# Circuit simulation of a tremolo pedal not working

Tags: circuit-design, simulation, guitar-pedal

im a electrical engineering student here in Brazil and i have to build a tremolo effect for a electric guitar, but i'm not having luck in the simulation of my circuit and i dont know if im simulating wrong or the program simply don't have enough 'power' to simulate the sound.
[image: CIRCUIT ON PROTEUS]

[image]

The input and the output are the same wave and sound

i already simulate a distortion pedal and had the distorted sound but im having trouble with this tremolo

Comment: It looks like you are wrongly trying to modulate the output of a power amplifier. This tremolo circuit has the guitar pickup at the input and its output feeds the input of the power amplifier that drives the speaker.

Comment: @Audioguru and how can I simulate this power amplifier ? Just an op amp ?

Comment: You don't need to simulate a power amplifier but, don't hang a load on the output. Also, make sure that your signal source (on the left connected to R4) has an internal impedance of circa 100 kohm.

Comment: @JonatanIaczinski, I'm just checking, but are you aware that guitar pedals go between the guitar and the amplifier and **not** between the amplifier and the loudspeaker? Guitar <---> pedal <---> amplifier <---> speaker. Your schematic shows it on the line *after* the amplifier.

Comment: I believe the problem is that the simulation has zero output impedance driving the circuit input, so the transistor has no effect even if it can sink kiloamperes in the simulator. Please try adding something that simulates a guitar pickup, like 47k resistor in series to input, and try again.

Comment: Can you show waveforms for the input and output? The schematic shows them connected with a wire, so there needs to be some finite resistance or impedance so the transistor Q1 can have some effect. Also, you should use actual models for Q1 and U1. The defaults may not be realistic.

Comment: An opamp is not a power amplifier so it cannot drive a speaker.